# Using the same function multiple times even though the vectors are different

Tags: c, vector

In the below code, I am saving and printing two vectors. This means I have created each function —`scanf()` and `printf()`— twice even though they are the same apart from the vector name they operate. How could I have only one `scanf()` and `printf()` functions, and still save and print as many vectors as I want? **N.b.** In this case, I am only working with static vectors.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int scanning_first_vector(int *vector1);
int printing_first_vector(int *vector1);

int scanning_first_vector(int *vector2);
int printing_first_vector(int *vector2);


int main()
{

    int vector1[5], vector2[5];

    printf("Please enter the first vector.\n");

    scanning_first_vector(vector1);
    printing_first_vector(vector1);

    printf("\nPlease enter the second vector.\n");

    scanning_first_vector(vector2);
    printing_first_vector(vector2);

    return 0;
}

int scanning_first_vector(int *vector1)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &vector1[i]);
    }
    return 0;   
}

int printing_first_vector(int *vector1)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        printf(" %d ", vector1[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int scanning_second_vector(int *vector2)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &vector2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int printing_second_vector(int *vector2)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        printf(" %d \n", vector2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: you're already successfully using one function for both.

Comment: You never call `XXX_second_vector()`, and don't need them.

Comment: Just rename `XXX_first_vector()` to `XXX_vector()`, since it works with any vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just did below the leaner version of the code after reading the comments — thank you, guys! :-) I understand now that I can use the same function & I only need to make sure I give distinctive names to the vectors in the `main()` function. It works well, but it would also be awesome to get confirmation that the way the code is done here is as lean & good as it can get :-) Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int scanning_vector(int *vector);
int printing_vector(int *vector);

int main()
{

    int vector1[5], vector2[5];

    printf("Please enter the first vector:\n");

    scanning_vector(vector1);
    printing_vector(vector1);

    printf("\nPlease enter the second vector:\n");

    scanning_vector(vector2);
    printing_vector(vector2);

    return 0;
}

int scanning_vector(int *vector)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &vector[i]);
    }
    return 0;   
}

int printing_vector(int *vector)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        printf(" %d ", vector[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```